# Scheduled Polling Interval Options

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssas

I am confused about the scheduled polling interval options in SSAS.  Say I want data to be updated every 10 minutes.  In the dimension's Storage Options dialog, the first tab says: "Update Cache Periodically" and allows me to specify rebuild every 10 minutes.  On the second tab it says "Scheduled Polling" and allows me to select a polling interval of 10 minutes as well.

What is the difference between rebuilding the cache every 10 minutes, and scheduled polling every 10 minutes?  Do both need to be specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good question, I would vote more than once if I could :)

Basically, the first tab tells you how the cache will be updated. Depending on the option, you need to configure how notification will be handled on the second tab.

So, getting your example. If you set "update cache periodically" to 10 minutes, it means that the cache will be completely rebuilt every 10 minutes, like drop it and recreate it. If you think about it, SQL Server doesnt need to tell SSAS to do the task, SSAS knows that every 10 minutes it has to reach to SQL Server to get new data. So, the configuration on the second tab is ignored.

Now, imagine you select option one "update cache when data changes". That means the cache will only be updated when the data on SQL Server changes. To do that, SSAS needs some sort of notification to know when the data has changed.

That's when the second tab gets in place, where you can select the type of notification. In your case, Schedule pooling, means that at an interval of 10 minutes, SSAS will run the query you specify on "pooling query" to check if data was changed and if yes, it will run the query on "processing query" to actually update the data.

FYI, as a notification mode is a lot easier to specify tracking tables. You dont need to write queries, just select the tables.

Comment: Thanks, I've been asking a series of questions in an attempt to figure out why I can't get proactive caching to work.  I tried turning on "update cache periodically" for 10 minutes, and nothing else, but that hasn't worked.  I'm still learning alot.